# Custom comment form in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, comments

I would like to customize the output of `comment_form()` function in WordPress.
To edit fields and textarea, I used the following code and all works fine.

```
<?php
    $req = get_option( 'require_name_email' );
    $fields =  array(
            // redefine author field
        'author' => '<p class="comment-form-author">' . '<label for="author">' . __( 'Name:' ) . ( $req ? ' <span class="required">*</span>' : '' ) . '</label>' .
        '<div class="input-prepend"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span><input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author'] ) . '" size="30"' . 'aria-required="true"' . ' required /></p>',
        'email'  => '<p class="comment-form-email"><label for="email">' . __( 'Email Address:' ) . ( $req ? ' <span class="required">*</span><br/>' : '' ) . '</label>' . 
        '<div class="input-prepend"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span><input required id="email" name="email" type="text" value="' . esc_attr(  $commenter['comment_author_email'] ) . '" size="30"' . 'aria-required="true"' . ' required /></div></p>',
        'url'  => '<p class="comment-form-url"><label for="url">' . __( 'Your Website:' ) . '</label>' . 
        '<div class="input-prepend"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-globe"></i></span><input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="' . esc_attr( $commenter['comment_author_url'] ) . '" size="30" /></div></p>'
        );
    $comments_args = array(
        'fields' => $fields,
            // redefine your own textarea (the comment body)
        'comment_field' => '<p class="comment-form-comment"><label for="comment">' . 'Comment' . '</label><textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="span12" rows="5" aria-required="true"></textarea></p>',
        );
    comment_form( $comments_args );
?>
```

This is the result:

[image: Custom comment form]

Now, I would like to add two CSS class (`class="btn btn-primary"`) for submit button; how can I do that without using jQuery?

**Note:**

For the solution, please read comments about answer marked with green sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As krizna said, you can modify your theme's `comments.php` file to alter the output of `comment_form()`. I think that might be your best bet in this situation.

If you take a look at the [Function Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comment_form#Parameters) for `comment_form()` in the Codex you'll notice that you can only modify the ID for the submit button, and not the class. There are a few tickets on Trac regarding this:

- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/20446
- http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15015

If modifying `comments.php` doesn't work for you in this situation, you can try applying one of the patches.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Patching the core, I cannot distribute to third parties my theme having the right layout for the submit button. I could use jQuery to add my classes, but I'd like to avoid this solution. There are other ways?

Comment: Gotcha. Is there any way you could just modify the corresponding CSS? And use the submit ID instead of the `btn` and `btn-primary` classes?

Comment: No. Using ID, I would unmake the structure of my CSS.

Comment: I did some more digging and was able to find a similar question on WordPress Answers. One of the responses suggests creating a new function to replace the comment_form() one: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19710/how-to-add-a-class-to-the-comment-submit-button#answer-19713

Comment: In my honest opinion, to date, it is the best solution for this issue. Thank you for help in this matter.

Comment: Glad to hear! Let me know if it does indeed solve your problem. I know it isn't ideal, but until the `comment_form()` function is updated it may be the only way.

Comment: Yes, with a custom function all works fine. Also I know it isn't ideal, but, for now, it is the best we can do for the purpose.